# delete row in foreign table without deleting main table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a main table called `user` with primary key `id`, this table has childs table which save details about the user. let say childs table are, `admin`, `member`, `spv`, these table have a foreign key `user_id` referencing to table `user` with `DELETE CASCADE` and `UPDATE CASCADE`.

now, I have the `user_id` in my php script, how do i delete the detail without specifying which table to delete from.

Comment: "how do i delete the detail without specifying which table to delete from" - this sounds a bit strange. Could you please post an example data before and after the desired operation?

Comment: You probably need to check in which child table the `user_id` exists. If it exists there, delete the row. What I would do is to store the type of user in the main table (or in relation table if there can be more then one type for each user), so you have a record of that and go straight to that table.

Comment: Did you try anything? How about [googling](https://www.google.de/search?q=mysql+delete+cascade&oq=mysql+delete+cascade&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? You could follow [this example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/). As a rule of thumb you should always explain what you tried, and point out at what point your  code failed.

Comment: @JanHolas: so there is no way except to check one by one in which table `user_id` exists?? i was hoping there is a way without looping in child table.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki: I can check the child table one by one then delete the row in the correct table, but I am just curious is there any way in `MySql` to delete only the child table without deleting main row in main table.

Comment: @DarielPratama Or you can probably do it in one query `DELETE FROM  admin, member, spv WHERE user_id = '$userId'`. Then it deletes the only rows from tables where given `user_id` is present

Comment: @JanHolas ahhh nice idea, how could I don't think about that @.@. thanks JanHolas

Comment: I just checked the manual and the syntax is a bit different: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html you need to use `DELETE FROM admin, member, spv USING admin, member, spv WHERE user_id = '$userId'`